# How to prove $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} :f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2\sqrt2x+9}+\sqrt{x^2-4\sqrt2x+16}\geq 5$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, radicals, alternative-proof

Suppose we need to prove  $$\forall x\in \mathbb{R} :f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2\sqrt2x+9}+\sqrt{x^2-4\sqrt2x+16}\geq 5$$
First I use plotting to show this and find $min$ of the function is greater than $5$
Then I used derivation anf find $f'=0$ root in $x\sim 2.15 $ ,by tracing sign of $f'$ we can easily show that point is $min$ 
$$f'=0 \to x\sim 2.098 \implies min=(2.098,5.65)$$ so $f(x)\geq 5$  .

The original question was about $k-10$ students , so we can't use derivation or plotting. 
My question is : How to prove it by an elementary method ?

My trial was :$$f(x)=\sqrt{(x-\sqrt2)^2+7}+\sqrt{(x-2\sqrt2)^2+8}$$This is obvious $$\sqrt{(x-\sqrt2)^2+7}+\sqrt{(x-2\sqrt2)^2+8}\geq \sqrt 7+\sqrt 8>5 $$ But :$\bf \text {at the same time ,it is impossible  }(x-\sqrt2)^2=0,(x-2\sqrt2)^2=0$
How can I describe it to $k-10 $ students ?
I truly appreciate your time and effort (for any Idea)

Comment: What does ``$k-10$ students'' mean?

Comment: @vadim123 :I f you name the last school $k-12 $ then 2 years sooner is $k-10$ . I mean use I dentitiy , inequaliity  ,...

Comment: $x$ cannot be equal to $\sqrt{2}$ and $2\sqrt{2}$ simultaneously so.... which is the problem with the trial?....

Comment: How do you describe *what*? And why do you want to prove that it is impossible to have $(x-\sqrt2)^2=(x-2\sqrt2)^2=0$? How does that help?

Comment: They do not have to be zero simultaneously. They are arbitrary positive numbers. Therefore your conclusion is right and there is no need to show that they are equal (actually they can not be equal to zero simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just explain that if $g(x),h(x)>0$ then
$$\min [g(x)+h(x)] \geq \min g(x) + \min h(x). $$